# CUstomized links in gsp

Tags: grails, groovy

I have some controllers in my grails application:-

```
LoginController
LogoutController
SearchableController
cirnele.SearchAllController
com.ten.cirnelle.domain.CustomerController
com.ten.cirnelle.domain.ProjectController
com.ten.cirnelle.domain.PurchaseOrderController
com.ten.cirnelle.domain.QuotationController
com.ten.cirnelle.domain.ResourceController
```

In Config.groovy, I have provided one of my configration:-

```
cirnelleControllerExclusions =['Login','Search','Searchable','Resource']
```

and from main.gsp, I am using:-

```
<g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">

    <g:if test="${grailsApplication.config.cirnelleControllerExclusions.contains(c.naturalName.split()[0]) == false}">

        <li class="controller"><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.naturalName.split()[0]}</g:link></li>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

this code is used to provide a menu like structure at the top of every view page and it is excluding 4 cotrollers, that i specified in Config.groovy to be display as a link in view pages.
but i have many users with different roles like

```
ROLE_PM
ROLE_SALES/BDM
ROLE_TEAMMEMBER
ROLE_ADMIN
```

and my requirement is that if an user with admin role logins, then he can view all the controllers as a link(except the 4) but if a user with PM role logins, then he cannot view CustomerController link and QuotationCotroller link.
so how can i customized my main.gsp to show menu links based on the role of user.
thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [spring security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core). There are tags for doing exactly what you want.

```
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
  <g:link controller="login" action="auth">Login</g:link>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_USER">
  <g:link class="create" controller="post" action="timeline">My Timeline</g:link>
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```